# Render Frontend Extension with Fluid error

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I try to to build an Extension for TYPO3 with frontend and backend. When trying to start the frontend I get this error:

```
1297645190: Ext Direct error in "TYPO3\CMS\Core\ExtDirect\ExtDirectApi" with namespace: "TYPO3"\n Try to clear the TYPO3 cache and / or use paramater no_cache=1 as parameter in URL typo3/ajax.php\n\n >
Check also the following points:\n - configuration in ext_localconf.php: registration key should be like "TYPO3.MyExtension.Sample"\n - URL typo3/ajax.php: namespace parameter should be like: "TYPO3.MyExtension"\n - javascript: method\'s name should be like: "TYPO3.MyExtension.Sample.myMethod"\n
```

Setup.txt

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE 
page.10 {
file = EXT:rere/Resources/Private/Templates/Pruefling/Show.html
layoutRootPath = EXT:rere/Resources/Private/Layouts
}
page.includeJS{
    file1 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js
    file2 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/js/bootstrap.js
    file3 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js
    file4 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/js/Chart.min.js
    file5 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/js/rereGlobal.js
    file6 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/js/notenverwaltung.js
}
page.includeCSS{
    file1 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/css/resultrepository.css
    file2 = EXT:rere/Resources/Public/css/bootstrap.min.css
}
```

ext_localconf.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        'rere.' . $_EXTKEY, 'rerefrontend', array(
    'Modul' => 'list, show, new, newFach, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Fach' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Note' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Pruefling' => 'setPruefling, list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Intervall' => 'new, create, edit, update',
    'Export' => 'exportPrueflinge, exportModuleUndFaecher, exportFach',
    'Import' => 'new, importPrueflinge, importBackUp',
    'Ajax' => 'searchPruefling',
    'Intervall' => 'new, create, edit, update'
        ),
        // non-cacheable actions
        array(
    'Modul' => 'list, show, new, newFach, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Fach' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Note' => 'list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Pruefling' => 'setPruefling, list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete',
    'Intervall' => 'new, create, edit, update',
    'Export' => 'exportPrueflinge, exportModuleUndFaecher, exportFach',
    'Import' => 'new, importPrueflinge, importBackUp',
    'Ajax' => 'searchPruefling',
    'Intervall' => 'new, create, edit, update'
        )
);
```

I tried without Javascript and CSS but same issue.
Setup is called with 
`<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE: EXT:rere/Configuration/TyposSript/setup.txt">`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use `<f:be.container>` in your **FE** plugin ?

I'm not gonna to give you correct answer as it's your own code you're talking about... you didn't even show it to us?

TIP is, if you don't need `f:layout` VH for some specific reason don't use it all - it's not required.